# How to inline elements with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make menubar at the top of my website.
It should looke like this:
[image]

The red square is my button.

My problem is that my headline and my button are not in the same line. So I tried to use a table but then there are both aligned to the left.
After that I used `float: right;` for my button.
It is now aligned right but in the next line.

How can I fix it so my button and my headline are in the same line and aligned like my picture.

HTML:

```
<div id="topbar">
   <h1>Fahrplan</h1>
   <button type="button" id="settings"></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 
  line-height: 44px;
}
#topbar button {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this kind of scenarios, you might consider using `position`s.

```css
#topbar {
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 
  line-height: 44px;
  background: #99f;
}
#topbar button {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <h1>Fahrplan</h1>
  <button type="button" id="settings"></button>
</div>
```

Here I have given `position` to both `#topbar` and the button. The `#topbar` has a `relative` position and button has an `absolute` position:

```css
#topbar {
  position: relative;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

And I have also adjusted the button to be vertically centred by using the negative margin of half the height. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think using `absolute` is a good option here, `float` will be idle, am sure OP doesn't want his elements roll behind that button if viewport goes small

Comment: @Mr.Alien Right. We can also suggest the OP to set a `min-width` or something. `:)`

Comment: It works but doesn't scale, what if you have two buttons? The CSS that knows about the height of other elements is also brittle. Having said that, I have used it in the past

Comment: @JuanMendes We can use `transform` in that case. Yes, even I have had bad hits because of my previous incidents. `:)`

Comment: I seriously don't understand why people downvote unnecessarily. I am ready to amend my answer upto your expectations. Please speak up.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather suggest you to use `absolute` along with `translateY()` to align your button vertically middle.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6mx6g4L7/2) (Note: Am using SCSS on jsFiddle so don't get confused with the syntax)

```
header {
  height: 40px;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;

  h4 {
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 10px;
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

I am using `position: absolute;` to move your button to the right. As far as vertical centering goes for your button, you can use `top: 50%` and `transform` to nudge your button exactly in the middle of your header vertically. It will always stay vertically centered without you declaring any static `height`.

Comment: Wow. This looks like a hybrid. When you are using `position`... Well, I am confused. Does this work?

Comment: @PraveenKumar `relative` would be redundant with a header in there so moved to absolute, but he don't have to use any more static height to vertically center the button.

Comment: @Paili Since you already know the button height, you don't need `transform` plus that's not supported by this stupid Internet Explorer. LoL.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Man, you changed your answer? The first answer you gave was interesting and that's why I was curious about it.

Answer (score 1):

For your interest, here's how to do it with inline-blocks.

```css
div > * {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
h1 { 
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:-40px;
  background-color:#4F81BD;
  color:#FFF;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 
  height: 44px;
}
button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right:-6px;
  border: 3px solid #8C3836;
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color:#C0504D;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
   <h1>Fahrplan</h1>
   <button type="button" id="settings"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick demo of how to do this using http://tachyons.io

```
<div class="bg-light-gray dt w-100">
  <div class="dtc v-mid w3"></div>
  <div class="dtc v-mid tc pv3">
    <h1 class="mv0 f5">Headline</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="dtc v-mid tr w3 pr2">
    <button class="bg-black br2 h2 w2"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:
    .br2 {
      border-radius: .25rem;
    }

```
.dt {
  display: table;
}

.dtc {
  display: table-cell;
}

.h2 {
  height: 2rem;
}

.w2 {
  width: 2rem;
}

.w3 {
  width: 4rem;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.bg-black {
  background-color: #111;
}

.bg-light-gray {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.pr2 {
  padding-right: .5rem;
}

.pv3 {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.mv0 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
}

.tr {
  text-align: right;
}

.tc {
  text-align: center;
}

.f5 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.v-mid {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/r21mdrzs/

The downside is that you include an empty div. The plus side is that even if you zoom in or out, change font-size or size of button, everything will always be aligned to the middle, not matter what. This is in my experience is less brittle than using magic number values for positioning.

Answer (score -1):

Give your headline float property;

```
.classNameGiveToHeading {
  float: left;
}
.buttonClassName {
  float: right;
}
```

**OR** give "float:right" to both of them as you like.

Comment: This will not work because the heading must be centered, as per the requirement.